# What is the replacement for MavenProjectBuilder which is deprecated in maven 3?

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-3

I'm writing a plugin which in part takes as an input groupId:artifactId:version, and interrogates it POM.

In Maven2, there was an option to use MavenProjectBuilder. I could download the pom for the input GAV, and using MavenProjectBuilder, build a MavenProject and thus interrogate all I need from this pom (dependencies, scm tag), etc.

In Maven3, MavenProjectBuilder is deprecated, and I couldn't find any resource on replacement for it. Usually when you deprecate a class you add @see to help developers use the new class. Maven developers didn't,

Thanks!

Asaf

Answer (score 4):

Though it's not specifically referenced in the 3.0.3 API (as you mentioned), I think [org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/DefaultProjectBuilder.html) (and the [interface](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuilder.html) it implements) is the likely replacement.  They seem to have done away with some of the convenience methods.